# Space efficient arrays

Tags: c++, bitwise

I needed a very space-efficient structure to store an array for which elements are unsigned integers with an upper bound known at runtime.

I'm not an expert in pointer arithmetic, so I'm not sure if what I did is the best way to achieve this.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>

namespace optimizationtools
{

using SpaceEfficientArray = uint64_t*;

class SpaceEfficientArrayFactory
{

public:

    using Index = int64_t;
    using Value = uint64_t;

    /** Constructor. */
    inline SpaceEfficientArrayFactory(
            Index number_of_elements,
            Value maximum_value);

    /** Get the number of elmeents. */
    inline Index number_of_elements() const { return number_of_elements_; }

    /** Get the maximum value allowed. */
    inline Value maximum_value() const { return maximum_value_; }

    /** Create a new array. */
    inline SpaceEfficientArray create_array() const;

    /** Set the value of an element. */
    inline void set(
            SpaceEfficientArray& array,
            Index element_id,
            Value value) const;

    /** Get the value of an element. */
    inline Value get(
            const SpaceEfficientArray& array,
            Index element_id) const;

private:

    /** Number of elements in the arrays. */
    Index number_of_elements_ = 0;

    /** Maximum value of the elements of the arrays. */
    Value maximum_value_ = 0;

    /** Number of bits for each elements. */
    std::size_t number_of_bits_for_each_element_ = 0;

    /** Real size to allocate for the arrays. */
    std::size_t array_size_ = 0;

};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

inline SpaceEfficientArrayFactory::SpaceEfficientArrayFactory(
        Index number_of_elements,
        Value maximum_value):
    number_of_elements_(number_of_elements),
    maximum_value_(maximum_value)
{
    if (maximum_value <= 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Maximum value must be greater than 1.");
    }

    // Compute number_of_bits_for_each_element_.
    // 1 -> 1
    // 2 -> 2
    // 3 -> 2
    // 4 -> 3
    // 5 -> 3
    // 6 -> 3
    // 7 -> 3
    // 8 -> 4
    number_of_bits_for_each_element_ = std::floor(std::log2(maximum_value)) + 1;

    // Compute array_size_.
    array_size_ = (number_of_elements_ * number_of_bits_for_each_element_ - 1) / (8 * sizeof(uint64_t)) + 1;
}

inline SpaceEfficientArray SpaceEfficientArrayFactory::create_array() const
{
    return new uint64_t[array_size_]();
}

inline void SpaceEfficientArrayFactory::set(
        SpaceEfficientArray& array,
        Index element_id,
        Value value) const
{
    std::size_t position_start = element_id * number_of_bits_for_each_element_;
    std::size_t position_end = position_start + number_of_bits_for_each_element_ - 1;
    std::size_t word_start_pos = position_start / (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));
    std::size_t word_end_pos = position_end / (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));

    if (word_start_pos == word_end_pos) {
        //        word
        // |---------------|
        //      |-------|
        // pos_start  pos_end
        std::size_t number_of_bits = position_start % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));
        uint64_t mask = ~((((uint64_t)1 << (number_of_bits_for_each_element_)) - 1) << number_of_bits);
        uint64_t word = array[word_start_pos];
        array[word_start_pos] = (word & mask) | (value << number_of_bits);

    } else {
        //     word_start      word_end
        // |---------------|---------------|
        //             |-------|
        //        pos_start  pos_end
        std::size_t number_of_bits_1 = (position_start % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t)));
        uint64_t mask_start = (((uint64_t)1 << number_of_bits_1) - 1);
        uint64_t word_start = array[word_start_pos];
        array[word_start_pos] = (word_start & mask_start) | (value << number_of_bits_1);

        std::size_t number_of_bits_2 = (position_end % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t))) + 1;
        uint64_t mask_end = ~(((uint64_t)1 << (number_of_bits_2)) - 1);
        uint64_t word_end = array[word_end_pos];
        array[word_end_pos] = (word_end & mask_end)
            | (value >> (number_of_bits_for_each_element_ - number_of_bits_2));
    }
}

inline SpaceEfficientArrayFactory::Value SpaceEfficientArrayFactory::get(
        const SpaceEfficientArray& array,
        Index element_id) const
{
    std::size_t position_start = element_id * number_of_bits_for_each_element_;
    std::size_t position_end = position_start + number_of_bits_for_each_element_ - 1;
    std::size_t word_start_pos = position_start / (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));
    std::size_t word_end_pos = position_end / (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));

    if (word_start_pos == word_end_pos) {
        //        word
        // |---------------|
        //      |-------|
        // pos_start  pos_end
        uint64_t word = array[word_start_pos];
        std::size_t number_of_bits_to_shift = position_start % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t));
        uint64_t mask = ((uint64_t)1 << (number_of_bits_for_each_element_)) - 1;
        return (word >> number_of_bits_to_shift) & mask;

    } else {
        //     word_start      word_end
        // |---------------|---------------|
        //             |-------|
        //        pos_start  pos_end

        std::size_t number_of_bits_1 = (position_start % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t)));
        uint64_t mask_start = ~(((uint64_t)1 << number_of_bits_1) - 1);
        uint64_t word_start = array[word_start_pos];

        std::size_t number_of_bits_2 = (position_end % (8 * sizeof(uint64_t))) + 1;
        uint64_t mask_end = ((uint64_t)1 << (number_of_bits_2)) - 1;
        uint64_t word_end = array[word_end_pos];

        return (((word_start & mask_start) >> number_of_bits_1)
                | ((word_end & mask_end) << (number_of_bits_for_each_element_ - number_of_bits_2)));
    }
}

}
```

The full version is [here](https://github.com/fontanf/optimizationtools/blob/master/optimizationtools/containers/space_efficient_array.hpp) with a [small unit test](https://github.com/fontanf/optimizationtools/blob/master/optimizationtools/containers/space_efficient_array_test.cpp).

Answer (score 4):

## Make the `class` own the actual array

Instead of having a `create_array()` member function that allocates and returns the actual array, make your class own and manage it:

```
class SpaceEfficientArray {
    …
    SpaceEfficientArray(Index number_of_elements, Value maximum_value);
    ~SpaceEfficientArray();
    …
    void set(Index element_id, Value value);
    Value get(Index element_id) const;

private:
    Value* data;
    …
};

SpaceEfficientArray::SpaceEfficientArray(…): …
{
    data = new Value[array_size];
}

SpaceEfficientArray::~SpaceEfficientArray()
{
    delete[] data;
}
```

And even better than doing your own manual memory allocation, just use `std::vector`:

```
class SpaceEfficientArray {
    …
    private:
    std::vector<Value> data;
    …
};

SpaceEfficientArray::SpaceEfficientArray(…): …
{
    data.resize(array_size);
}
```

Then you don't need a destructor to clean up the allocated memory.
With this, your unit test would now look like:

```
TEST(SpaceEfficientArray, Test1)
{
    SpaceEfficientArray array(10, 120000);

    array.set(0, 118387);
    EXPECT_EQ(array.get(0), 118387);
    EXPECT_EQ(array.get(1), 0);
    …
    EXPECT_EQ(array.get(4), 0);
}
```

## You can make it look like a regular array

Instead of having `get()` and `set()` member functions, you could make an `operator[]` that works the same like in `std::vector` and `std::array`. Of course, you cannot have it return a reference to the underlying array, but just like [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), you could have it return a proxy object that knows how and where to read/write the actual data. Similarly, you could also add `begin()` and `end()` member functions.

While this is going to be a bit more work to figure out, the advantage is then that you can use your space-efficient array in a more natural way, and that many [STL algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) would then also work with it.

## Calculating the number of bits needed

Using floating point math operations to get the number of bits is unnecessary; there are [ways](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) to do it with just integer operations. But even better, since C++20 you can just use [`std::bit_width()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I separated the array on purpose. I agree that it makes the class more cumbersome to use. But I have billions of arrays, which can have the size of just two `uint64_t`. Adding a single non-mandatory attribute in a SpaceEfficientArray class may cause a significant overhead. Thank you for the link about the number of bits

Comment: If you want to separate the actual data from the class that accesses it, consider making it work like [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span). And if you know the maximum value and/or the size at compile time, you could make your class a template with those things as parameters, so they don't take up space at runtime.